# Is there a way to show completion level?

Tags: kiwi-tcms

As a test lead, I want to convey to stakeholders the current status of testing based on projects under test.

When I view telemetry, test plans, test cases, and test executions, I don't see a chart or summary of the planned work, nor a comparison of the planned work versus the completed work. I also don't see this kind of measure listed in the [planned updates to Telemetry](https://kiwitcms.org/blog/kiwi-tcms-team/2019/03/03/legacy-reports-become-telemetry/).

If Kiwi doesn't present this data, has anyone worked out a good way to gather it and present it outside of Kiwi?

Comment: >nor a comparison of the planned work versus the completed work
Test Run -> Nr. of cases (planned work) - Nr. of done tests (completed work).

Comment: Thanks @Prome. That does give the view for a specific Test Run. I am looking for a view at a higher level than the Test Run. The level of Test Plan would be good, though I would like a view from a Product/Version/Build level.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you are asking for doesn't currently exist but sounds like a good report to have. It needs more definitions though.

> As a test lead, I want to convey to stakeholders the current status of
>   testing based on projects under test.

First let me start by saying in Kiwi TCMS there are Products, not projects. One product may comprise of many projects and vice versa. You may also have multi-layered products.

So let's define what a project means for you ? Is that a collection of products or something different ?

How do you define "planned work" ?

@Prome suggested planned work == number of test cases but that is incomplete. I can have test cases which are never executed during a specific timeframe, such that are already old and obsolete (but you don't want to remove them b/c you want to keep historical data), you may have a TestRun which is already finished but contains test cases which have not been executed (reasons may vary).

So how do you "plan testing work" in your team currently ?

Comment: Currently, we're creating a separate Product for every Epic. Good enough, though not ideal because Components are tied to Products and therefore common ones can't be shared across Epics/Products, but that's not a big deal. (answering in multiple comments because comments are short.)

Comment: The granularity of an Epic is high enough to equal a project, though of course in practice and in Jira, all projects have multiple Epics. But for now, we are saying that a Kiwi Product = a Company Project.

Comment: I would like to see a report that showed the results of a query similar to "for this Product, find all associated test cases that are in states (x, y, z, etc.) and which are associated with test executions that are in states (x, y, z, etc.) And to support this, I'd like at least one more status, "Obsolete' to keep them out of these queries. We could use the current status of "Disabled", but I don't think that's precise enough,

Comment: I would also like for the same report/query to be executable against other organizational containers and traits, such as test plans and components. And I would like it to be able to follow parent test plans down to their children.

Comment: I think that, without any modifications to Kiwi, I could extract this info from the DB and stick it into a reporting tool. If I do end up doing that (other work is currently higher priority), I'll share those queries if they'd be helpful.

Comment: I need some time to wrap my head around the rest of your comments. FYI ATM we've got somebody else pushing their test data into Elastic Search and doing their own reports. Contributions from their side will be coming soon, hope you can contribute as well.  You can also bundle your own code as a Kiwi TCMS plugin and install it into your local instance (see docs).

Comment: > "for this Product, find all associated test cases that are in states (x, y, z, etc.) and which are associated with test executions"  ::: TestCases do have statuses (CONFIRMED, DISABLED, NEED_UPDATE) which are only good for peer review. Only CONFIRMED TestCases can be added to TestRun and hence there exist only TestExecutions for CONFIRMED TestCases. IOW you can't execute a test if it has not been confirmed. You can disable the TC later and the TE & result will stay available though.  TE statuses can be modified and are flexible. TC statuses are scheduled for removal.

Comment: When you talk about "completion level" do you mean "how many of the scheduled tests have been actually executed during a specific sprint/etc" ? Because if you are this translates to "show me % of TestExecutions for Product X where TE.status is still neutral (0)" - that is show me anything which doesn't have a decisive PASS/FAIL, e.g. completeness.  Which you do have as a progress bar in Execution trends telemetry.